# One-colour album cover with nothing else that one colour (no writings, no shades)?

Tags: album, artwork

I wonder if there were an album that has a cover with one and only one colour.

Metallica's [*Black Album*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallica_(album)) has a snake and the band name logo written on it.

The Beatle's [*White Album*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles_(album)) also has the band name on it.

I'm looking for albums that reached Billboard, which cover has absolutely nothing else than one absolute colour, not varying shades of the same colour..

I am not trying to identify a specific album, I just want to know if some artists dared to do it, since the ones I know still have some writings on it.

Comment: To add to the endless list, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brown_Album_(Martin/Molloy_album).

Comment: Why was the identify-this label removed? I don't want identify-this stuff in my frontpage feed. If that specific identify-this label isn't accurate, please add one that is so I can add it to my ignore list. If it's not an identify-this question, it is an endless list question, and should be closed as such.

Comment: This question doesn't have one answer, and not because it's subjective. It's an endless list question, that will only increase with time. There's no best answer, or correct one, regardless of votes and OP's choice for correct answer.

Comment: @AntondB, I'm sorry you fell that way, but tags are not supposed to hide questions you don't like, I won't create a tag named "for-questions-that-AntondB-does-not-like". It becomes an endless list question when you actually know the answer, I didn't suspect there were so much answers.

Comment: Hiding specific questions through tags is one of the few uses they have. They provide that exact functionality for that exact purpose. It's a question asking for the cover of an album, so I don't think it's intellectually honest to suggest that any label would fit, or that there's no other label choice than identify-what-he-said. You are asking about the characteristics of the cover of an album, so something similar to identify-this-cover should be enough. I was going to, but didn't want to create a new tag, or thought that you would mind, since it's so obviously an identify-this question.

Comment: Tags are their implementation of "ignore user", see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3411/247309   "You can ignore tags because they represent content, not users."

Comment: Tags do have a follow and hide feature, but I don' think this falls under the identify this album tag . I do feel like this is going to turn into an endless list, but if we can add specific information like the first for the most commercially successful one we can keep it from being an endless list, but due to the current answers it may be better to ask as a new question.

Comment: @Brahadeesh yes because a new albums can always come out that fill that requirement.

Answer (score 5):

If the "Explicit Lyrics" sticker doesn't count, then Lupe Fiasco's [Food & Liquor II: The Great American Rap Album Pt. 1](https://www.discogs.com/it/Lupe-Fiasco-Food-Liquor-II-The-Great-American-Rap-Album-Pt-1/master/889602) album has a completely black cover.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_%26_Liquor_II:_The_Great_American_Rap_Album_Pt._1):

> [the album] debuted at number 5 on the US Billboard 200 chart, selling 89,778 copies in its first week"

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the edition, but Prince's [Black Album](https://www.discogs.com/Prince-The-Black-Album/master/22037) has typically been released with a fully black cover and just a sticker. It [peaked at 47 on December 10th, 1994](https://www.billboard.com/music/prince/chart-history/TLP/song/176702).

Another all-black one is [the This is Spinal Tap soundtrack](https://www.discogs.com/Spinal-Tap-From-The-Original-Motion-Picture-Soundtrack-This-Is-Spinal-Tap/master/19944). It [peaked at 121 on June 9th, 1984](https://www.billboard.com/music/Soundtrack/chart-history/TCL/song/383160).

Comment: Interestingly, the Prince one managed to have no logos, small legal text even on the back side!